# unexpected T_ECHO in link?

Tags: php, json

i have a small problem with echo in php

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];  
// copy file content into a string var
$json_file = file_get_contents('link.com?id_select='echo $id;');
```

how do i show the value of GET ID into the link?

Thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use concatenation you do that with a dot like so:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('link.com?id_select='.$id);
```

Comment: Thanks <3, i got it now <3 :)!

Comment: Because you're not doing it correct do it like this: `index.php?id_select='.$id.'&op_select` next time add the whole url in the question.

Comment: im sorry i will remember it to next time. thanks for the help, i will aprove the anwser in just a moment :)